# What are some well designed Ruby projects suitable for study of coding the Ruby way?

Tags: ruby

I am starting out on Ruby and have heard that there is a 'Ruby way' of coding. What are some projects, apart from Ruby on Rails, that are suitable for study and is agreed upon as well designed?

Comment: Why is studying Ruby on Rails not a suitable option?

Comment: Since I am not familiar with web applications, studying the language first seems prudent rather than attempting to study rails also and ending up nowhere

Comment: @DJTripleThreat: While Rails changed the way we think about idiomatic Ruby, it is in itself far from idiomatic or well-designed.

Comment: Even things like Prawn would require you to be somewhat familiar with PDF.  What types of things are you planning to work on?

Answer (score 5):

[Prawn](http://Prawn.MajesticSeaCreature.Com/) was explicitly created to be not only a damn good PDF generation library, but also designed from the ground up as an example of well-designed, well-factored, idiomatic Ruby code. Prawn also spawned the [Ruby Best Practices book](http://RubyBestPractices.Com/) and the [RBP Blog](http://Blog.RubyBestPractices.Com/).